# Model Popup in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

Can some one Guide me to work with these things...

What is Model popup in iphone.
how to display a View as a Model Popup.
Is it possible with the subview as well or not...

Any Code or links will be more helpful

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source and description regarding the popup view for that following link to use

[Popup Bubbles](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popup-bubbles-tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can present a ViewController modally using the `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go through iOS SDK documentation. Everything is explained there..

[Views and Windows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503)

[view controller guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)